# d3 on brush triangle symbols disappears

Tags: d3.js, timeline, brush

The grey strip in the lower area allows the user to spread the data across x axis .[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adithyavr/LfBva/10/) Everything is resizing apart from the triangle symbols which are generated initially but disappear as soon as I  redraw using the brush (*ps: this happen only when i run the code from the same code from the browser and not jsfiddle!*)

1. My axis increases in length but 0min is repeated 3 to 4 times instead of showing 0.1 0.2 0.3 etc

`milestone_marks.selectAll(".milestone_markers")
        .data(milestones)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle-down'))
        .attr('class', 'milestone_markers')
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + x__axis(d.processing_time) + "," + -7 + ")";})`

and in the brushed function I write the following:

`d3.select('.milestone_marks').selectAll('path').data(milestones).attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle-down')).attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x__axis(d.processing_time) + "," + -7 + ")";})`

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: I have added the d3js.org script instead of the d3 on my system . Any ideas why ?  That is the reason it is not working in min